# @ViewChild component undefined when trying to call async variable

Tags: angular, asynchronous, viewchild, viewchildren

I used @ViewChildren component:

```
@ViewChildren("MyTest2Component") public myTest2Component: QueryList<MyTest2Component>


public ngAfterViewInit() {

this.myTest2Component.changes.subscribe((comps: QueryList <MyTest2Component>) =>
{
    console.log(comps.first.data); // data is async, here is undefind
});
```

}

but when trying to call async variable **data**, return **undefind**

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: How does your `MyTest2Component` look like?

Comment: my MyTest2Component is a package and I cant change its.

Answer (score 4):

In your child component, you can define an event to notify the parent when the data changes as below.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component',
  template: '<child-component (dataChanged)="onChildDataChanged($event)"></child-component>',
  styles: ['']
})
export class ParentComponent {
    onChildDataChanged(newData) {
        // tweak with new data
    }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  template: '<div></div>',
  styles: ['']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
    @Output() dataChanged: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
    
    ngOnInit(): void {
        someAsyncOperation.subscribe(data => {
            this.dataChanged.emit(data);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: MyTest2Component is a package and I cant change its.

Comment: This is sad... Then, the only way out is to check perodically whether the data is populated using `setInterval` and you can use clearInterval to stop checking when you have the data. An example usage of setInterval and clearInterval methods is [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp)